Can't verify phone number in google play console
I'm trying to verify my phone number in the Google Play Console, but I keep encountering the following error message:
"We can't verify your phone number at the moment. If this error persists, try verifying by receiving a call instead."
I have entered my phone number in the correct format: (Country code, followed by my mobile number without the leading zero).
Expecting the verification to complete successfully.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/115145

You have tried it too often. Wait 24 hours.

I've been experiencing this issue for over 3 months, despite waiting long periods between attempts. The problem persists even after trying again after 24 hours.

Im getting the same problem with a UK landline number. Sending  text doesn't work since it's not a mobile nr.

This seems helpful

Same issue.
SMS & Call options are working for verifying the developer account.
Extension is alredy applied and there is only 21 days remained.
Google Developer Support keeps silence.

Yes, exactly the same story.

Did you guys found a solution?

Not yet, still looking for a solution.

Had the same error, I tried with 3 different phone numbers from different countries. First of all your phone number must be set up in 2FA for your verified account. Second your phone number should be from the country of the selected payments method.
How I solved it:

First of all wait 72 hours before the next try!!!
Sign out all google account from Chrome. Clear all cache and coockies from the Chrome for all time. I tried it in Win11, cause in Ubuntu failed.
Sign in to google settings with your developer account.
Add/Change 2FA mobile phone number you gonna verify in your Google Account. In my case I changed the Ukrainian number to another country.
Sign in to Play Console in Chrome, 2FA phone number will be verified at this step. You can try in incognito mode.
Wait 72 hours.
Now start Developer Console verification with sms.


If you check the browser inspect tab you can see ("Quota Exceeded Error" OR "Too Many Requests Error")

Quota Exceeded Error:

Try using a different phone number.
Test during low-traffic hours (e.g., around 11:00 AM GMT) to improve
success chances.


Too Many Requests Error:

Wait 7-10 days for a temporary block to lift.
Clear your browser's cache and cookies before retrying.



For a detailed step-by-step guide with these issues, check out the full blog post.

No, i got "We can't verify your phone number at the moment. If this error persists, try verifying by receiving a call instead. " error

Check browser console errors not displayed error (see this tutorial: https://idafncellphone.blogspot.com/p/google-play-console-phone-verification.html)
